# Runtime formula evaluation

Tags: c, parsing, fortran, bison, yacc

I would like to evaluate formulas which a user can input for many data points, so efficiency is a concern.  This is for a Fortran project, but my solutions so far have been centered on using a yacc/bison grammar, so I will probably use Fortran's iso_c_binding feature to interface to yyparse().

The preferred (so far) solution would be an small extension of the classic `mfcalc` calculator example from the Bison manual, with the bison grammar made to recognize a (single) variable name as well (which is not hard).

The question is what to do in the executable statements.  I see two options there.

First, I could simply evaluate the expression as it is parsed, as in the `mfcalc` example.

Second, I could invoke the bison parser once for parsing and for creating a stack-based (reverse polish) representation of the formula being parsed, so
`2 + 3*x` would be translated into `2 3 * +` (of course, as the relevant data structure).

The relevant part of the grammar would look like this:

```
%union {
    double val;
    char *c;
    int fcn;
  }

%type <val> NUMBER
%type <c> VAR
%type <fcn> Function

/* Tokens and %left PLUS MINUS etc. left out for brevity */

%%
...

Function:
      SIN     { $$=SIN; }
      | COS     { $$=COS; }
      | TAN     { $$=TAN; }
      | SQRT    { $$=SQRT; }

Expression:
      NUMBER { push_number($1); }
      | VAR  { push_var($1); }
      | Expression PLUS Expression { push_operand(PLUS); }
      | Expression MINUS Expression { push_operand(MINUS); }
      | Expression DIVIDE Expression { push_operand(DIVIDE); }
      | MINUS Expression %prec NEG { push_operand(NEG); }
      | LEFT_PARENTHESIS Expression RIGHT_PARENTHESIS;
      | Function LEFT_PARENTHESIS Expression RIGHT_PARENTHESIS { push_function($1); }
      | Expression POWER Expression { push_operand(POWER); }
```

The functions push_... would put the formula into an array of structs, which which contain a struct holding the token and the yacc union.

The RPN would then be interpreted using a very simple (and hopefully fast) interpreter.

So, the questions.

Is the second approach valid?  I **think** it is from what I understand about bison (or yacc's) way of handling shift and reduce (basically, this will shift a number and reduce an expression, so the order should be guaranteed to be correct for RPN), but I am not quite sure.

Also, is it worth the additional effort over simply evaluating the function using the $$ construct (the first approach)?

Finally, are there other, better solutions?  I had considered using syntax trees, but I don't think the additional effort is actually worth it.  Also, I tend to think that using trees is overkill where an array would do just nicely :-)

Comment: How many times do you evaluate the same expression?

Comment: Some hundred thousands of times, maybe a up to million or so. I will also have to generate derivatives, which I plan to do numerically.

Answer (score 1):

It's only slightly more difficult to generate three-address virtual ops than RPN. In effect, the RPN is a virtual stack machine. The three-address ops -- which can also easily go into an array -- are probably faster to interpret, and will probably be more flexible in the long term.

The main advantage of parsing the expression into some internal form is that it is likely to be faster to evaluate the internal form than to reparse the original string. That may not be the case, but it usually is because converting floating-point literals into floating-point numbers is (relatively speaking) quite slow.

There is also the intermediate case of tokenizing the expression (into an array), and then directly evaluating while parsing the token stream. (In effect, that makes bison your virtual machine.)

Which of these strategies is the best depends a lot on details of your use case, but none of them are difficult so you could try all three and compare.

Comment: Thanks. I will give the option of tokenizing into an array, and then using the bison parser to evaluate this, a spin. Sounds like a good alternative (also from the point of view of programmer development time :-)